# React Three Fiber weird problems

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have been using React Three Fiber for a while, but now I am suddenly running into a problem that I really can't get my head around. I install a normal React project followed by npm install three @react-three/fiber @react-three/drei.

So far so good, I can add a canvas and some geometry. But when I try to add OrbitControls, Environment or basically whatever else, I get this error:

"Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/types/animated' in '/Users/jonathan/WS/rtf-configurator-test/node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist'
Did you mean 'animated.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@react-spring/types/animated' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist/index.mjs 1596:0-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/types/animated' in '/Users/jonathan/WS/rtf-configurator-test/node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist'
Did you mean 'animated.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@react-spring/types/animated' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist/index.mjs 1597:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/types/interpolation' in '/Users/jonathan/WS/rtf-configurator-test/node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist'
Did you mean 'interpolation.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@react-spring/types/interpolation' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

webpack compiled with 2 errors
"

What is this?!

I don't even know what to try!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently downgrading the version for `react-spring` works.
Find out more on this open issue on GitHub https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/1311

I solved it by downgrading to `react-spring=^9.5.2`